# Matrix Marginalization (marginal distribution)

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I would like to do a marginalization from two Matrices to obtain a third matrix.
Basically, I have two Mat objects of size (4x1) and I want marginalize them to obtain a third 4 by 4 matrix that is row standardized. This is done by taking the first row of the first Mat object and multiply with each row of the second Mat object to fill the first row of the third 4x4 Mat with each row element multiplication being divided by that row's sum as illustrated in the diagram below. And also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution). 
Find below coding steps I have taken so far and got a bit stack....
[image: Diagrammatic illustration]

```
const int nStates = 9;
register int iii, jjj;
float mMatrix[nStates][3] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};


//Pixelwise transitions
Mat nPot1 = Mat(nStates, 1, CV_32FC1,mMatrix );
Mat nPot2 = Mat(nStates, 1, CV_32FC1,mMatrix );
Mat NodeTransitions(nStates, nStates, CV_32FC1); NodeTransitions.setTo(Scalar(1.0f));
float fN1;
for( iii = 0; iii < nStates; iii++){
    float * pPot1 = nPot1.ptr<float>(iii);
    float * pPot2 = nPot2.ptr<float>(iii);
    float * pNodeTrans = NodeTransitions.ptr<float>(iii);
    //nPot1.at<float>(iii,0);
    //nPot2.at<float>(iii,0);
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i =0; i < nStates; i++){
        fN1 =  pPot1[i]*pPot2[iii];
        cout << fN1 << "\t";
    }
    for(jjj = 0; jjj < nStates; jjj++){
        //pNodeTrans[jjj] = fN1;
    }
    //cout << endl;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compute the outer product and then normalize each row using the L1 norm.

I'll call your two vectors `x` and `y`. Then compute `R = x * y.t()` and normalise `R` along each row.

In OpenCV there is the [Mat::dot](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=dot#double%20Mat::dot%28InputArray%20m%29%20const) function but it is only defined for vectors and you'd need it for matrices (as you transpose one of your inputs making it a 1xn matrix or a row vector).

This means, you'd have to do it by hand. You could also do these matrix multiplication with [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page). Consider this, if you do a lot of matrix multiplications and they don't represent images and such.

Untested code:

```
const int nStates = 9;
float mMatrix[nStates][1] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

//Pixelwise transitions
Mat nPot1 = Mat(nStates, 1, CV_32FC1,mMatrix );
Mat nPot2 = Mat(nStates, 1, CV_32FC1,mMatrix );
Mat NodeTransitions(nStates, nStates, CV_32FC1);
NodeTransitions.setTo(Scalar(1.0f)); // Why are you doing this?
float fN1;

// Pass one, compute outer product.
for (int row=0; row < nStates; row++) {
    for (int col=0; col < nStates; col++) {
        fN1 = nPot1.at<float>(row, 0) * nPot2.at<float>(col, 0);
        NodeTransitions.at<float>(row, col)  = fN1;
    }
}

// Pass two, normalise each row.
for (int row=0; row < nStates; row++) {
    // find sum of this row
    fN1 = 0; // using fN1 for sum now.
    for (int col=0; col < nStates; col++) {
        fN1 += NodeTransitions.at<float>(row, col);
    }
    // Now divide all elements in row by sum
    for (int col=0; col < nStates; col++) {
        // divide value at row,col by fN1.
        NodeTransitions.at<float>(row, col) /= fN1;
    }
}
```

### Comment on efficiency

Given that you have `nStates` quite small, this code should be efficient enough. It looks like, you got stuck trying to do all of this in one go. There is no need to.

Comment: With this line "NodeTransitions.setTo(Scalar(1.0f)); // Why are you doing this?" I just fill up the matrix with some values so that it is not empty :)

Comment: It won't be empty after you've computed the result. No need to fill it with ones first and then immediately overwrite them.

Comment: The algorithm works super. Thanks for the help, initially I was avoiding many loops but I guess its fine. Thanks again :)

Comment: Feel free to upvote the answer, if you feel it helped.

Comment: I just plugged the code into my main algorithm and the computational efficiency has reduced significantly. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Did your old code produce correct results? If not, then it isn't fair to compare fast-and-wrong with slow-but-correct code. Why are you using `cv::Mat` for this, is there a special reason? If not, you could use Eigen, or just `std::vector`/C-style arrays. Maybe try to measure where my suggested code is slow.

Comment: @Unapledra My code produces correct results. I am using Mat because my libraries works with Mat even if I use vector I will end converting the Mat to vector for computation then convert it back to Mat for further computation, so I guess this will be almost equivalent to the current state. So far I appreciate your solution, just that efficiency has reduced :)

Comment: I don't get it. Why would you ask the question if you had working code already?

Comment: @@Unapiedra I think there is some misunderstanding here. This part of the code (method) is an additional part which was not in my old code i.e. I am improving a classification method and hence I introduced this part into the code into my old code. So I was comparing the efficiency of before and after I improved the method, but ofcourse this is not part of the old one. So I hope now its clear.